# Association rules and itemsets

Tags: association-rules

Reading about `association rules mining` made me somehow confused. I am wondering if this is possible that in a transaction, an item occurs more than once? Considering the following database as a reference:

```
Transaction id  Items
         t1     {1,4,1}
         t2     {2}
         t3     {1,2,1}
         t4     {2,2}
         t5     {1, 2, 3, 5}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so. Are your item sets destined for the apriori algorithm? The apriori algorithm is based on the presence or absence of items in, say, a shopping basket. It doesn't care about how many items you buy of a particular kind. Alternatively, you could treat different quantities as different items -- so that a six-pack of beer is different from a two-four.

Comment: Yes, I am referring to apriori algorithm. what do you mean two-four? in addition, how can I tell the algorithm that these 6 items are actually 6 instances of a same type?

Comment: A two-four is a pack of 24 bottles of beer. It's a Canadian thing. The apriori algorithm uses a big transaction matrix - items in columns, transactions in rows, with a 0 or 1 in each cell. It can't deal with "6 items of the same type", so you would have to clean the data first: "Joe bought beer and chips"; "Jane bought beer and beef".  There may be a different algorithm out there that handles multiples. Why do you want to make that distinction? i.e. buying 6 beers is associated with buying 2 large pizzas? But buying 5 beers is associated with .... buying fish sticks.

Comment: the distinction is due to the fact that , in my mind, buying 6 of a soft drink with something would have more `weight` compare to buying , say, 2 of the same soft drink with some other item. In other words, it would be more `associated` to the first item compare to the second item. does that make any sense? I hope it does.

Comment: If you want to relate quantity to presence - as in the more diapers you buy the more likely you are to buy baby food - then you are into logistic regression models. However these only work for one response at a time. For groceries, the quantity is a function of how many people you are feeding. Lots of hot dogs go with lots of hot dog buns. A large quantity might indicate that someone is holding a party, or in a hardware situation, that the purchaser is a builder. You would need a lot of domain specific knowledge to build a model like that. apriori isn't that smart.

Comment: Actually my real model is not about shopping list but it can be seen as what I explained. In this case, that apriori is a little dumb for such functionalities, what is your suggestion? I mean in terms of statistic modeling.

Comment: I've been thinking about this but I can't some up with any ideas without knowing more about your use case. Sorry.

Comment: Ok, Here is more about my case. I am trying to associate URLs with users' query. Each URL has different segments which are surrounded between two `\`s, To adopt association rules to this case, I regarded user queries as items and each URL as a transaction. The occurrence of any of the user query in the URL would be set accordingly,

Comment: But since there might be more than one occurrence of a user's query's keyword, there is a problem. But however, I came to a solution that instead of considering each URL as a transaction, we make a database for each URL and not all URLs and then,

Comment: each segment can be seen as transaction. There is almost no case that a segment has more than one occurrence of any keyword. Hence, the problem would be to find URLs with highest Confidence and Support value for more keyword occurrence. For example  if the user query has 3 keywords, the problem is to find a set of URL candidates that has the highest support and confidence value for the occurrence of all the 3 keyword, if not, then for 2 and so on.

Comment: Here there might be a problem that a URL can have a higher support and confidence for itemset of two keywords while we have other URLs that have lower support and confidence but for itemset of all the 3 keywords. So I do not know which one to pick. In addition, I am not sure if my idea is making any sense or if I explained it clearly, so you may tell me about it.